# how to create a branch from a remote master in SourceTree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a git master in my SourceTree, and I want to create a branch on another computer. How I can do this? (Master = Remote, in the same network)

Comment: I find it funny how both answers are using the git command line. I came here looking for a solution to do this in the GUI. Would expect that to be possible, it's such a common task!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create the branch locally

```
git checkout -b branch_name
```

And then push to remote

```
git push -u remote-name branch-name
```

Then in the remote

```
 git pull branch-name
```

And it will automatically be created locally.

Comment: ok, thanks for early response, but how I could identify the remote?ç

Comment: The remote should be added previously. see https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote

Comment: and, where should I write these sentences?

Comment: What I want is to pass a copy of my project that is in my computer, to my laptop. And to check the two computers from version changes. But I do not use any Git server, which the computer would have the master

Answer (score 1):

On another machine connect SourceTree to master (clone)

Then with shell navigate to project folder and run such:

`git branch -r` (will show all remote branches)

`git checkout --track origin/[branch name]`

repeat checkout for all branches - SourceTree will get them almost immediately